# AdaptiveCards dropdown not working on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, adaptive-cards

For some reason, Microsoft AdaptiveCards dropdown is not working on iOS.
What I'm I missing?

Here's the Json:
[Json](https://gist.github.com/Jkurbs/360c4b2652afa54c59fa35ad59f7fa96)

Here's the code I'm using to render the card:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "adaptiveCard", withExtension: "json")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let jsonStr = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    
let cardParseResult = ACOAdaptiveCard.fromJson(jsonStr);
let config = ACOHostConfig()
if((cardParseResult?.isValid)!) {
    let renderResult = ACRRenderer.render(cardParseResult!.card, config: config, widthConstraint: Float(bounds.width))
    if(renderResult?.succeeded ?? false) {
        if let view = renderResult?.view {
            context.coordinator.setDelegate(view: view)
            return view
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the screen:
[image: Screenshot]